# android app doesn't go on with if code

Tags: android

in my android app i have this code part:

```
    Log.e("-->",DataString);
    ArrayList<String> ACList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] ACString = DataString.split(";");

    Log.e("-->", "AC LENGTH: "+ACString.length);

    int x = 0;
    while (x < ACString.length) {
       String[] DataSplit = ACString[x].split("-");

       if (!ACList.contains(DataSplit[1])) {
           Log.e("-->", "VALUE NOT IN LIST: "+DataSplit[1]);
           ACList.add(x,DataSplit[1]);
       }
       x++;
   }
   Log.e("-->", "===================");
```

Problem is:
I really get the Log "Value not in list" if the value isn't in the list.
But I don't get the Log "Next LOG".

then i get the Log "Next Log"
Any Ideas? :/

**UPDATE**

```
01-12 19:58:47.406 E: Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka|Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka
01-12 19:58:47.406 E: AC LENGTH: 4
01-12 19:58:47.406 E: ===================
01-12 20:02:18.952 E: Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka|Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka|Eier3;Rewew4
01-12 20:02:18.952 E: AC LENGTH: 5
01-12 20:03:26.124 E: Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka|Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka|Eier3;Rewew4
01-12 20:03:26.124 E: AC LENGTH: 5
01-12 20:04:00.961 E: Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka|Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka|Eierlauf;Rewew
01-12 20:04:00.961 E: AC LÄNGE: 5
01-12 20:04:31.444 E: Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka|Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka
01-12 20:04:31.444 E: AC LENGTH: 4
01-12 20:04:31.444 E: ===================
01-12 20:06:27.367 E: Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka|Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka|Hhgu;ZgG Hhh
01-12 20:06:27.367 E: AC LENGTH: 5
```

If the Length 4, the Log "===================" will be shown. but with length 5 not. WHY NOT? :'(

**NEXT UPDATE**
i can confirm, that the Log "===================" only will shown, if the AC Length is < 4. it drives me crazy

Comment: Try stepping through your code to see what is going on. Do you get any exceptions perhaps?

Comment: how can i see if i get any exceptions ?

Comment: Give and example string where this is happening - currently you are splitting some text into an array, then into a second array - it would help to see a test case string you are using this with.  Exceptions, if not handled, will crash the app, and show up (usually) as a lot of red text in the log - if this is happening post the log/stacktrace also.

Comment: i put the test string into post 1.mmmmh. a few minutes ago i can run the script 5x without problems.
but now the script dont show "Next Log" again. no error. the only message that i get is: 01-12 19:39:24.526 E: |CAC| readCallback: end of stream

Comment: i updated my first post.

Comment: This output cannot be from your code. If you split the first line, it should have 5 elements, not 4. Also, I am missing the `-->` tag, and there is all of a sudden `LÄNGE` instead of `LENGTH`. Post the *actual* output from LogCat please.

Comment: what do yo mean? in my first post is not the word "LÄNGE". Its LENGTH.  And this String Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka|Pute;Rewe|Eier;Edeka have 4 elements. You can believe me - this Output is form Code of Post 1